# “only position independent executables (PIE) are supported”

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am using FFMPEG support library to convert bunch of images to video. It works fine on earlier version of the lollipop. But in the lollipop it generates the following error. `***error: only position independent executables (PIE) are supported.***` I know the PIE Security restrictions has been changed in lollipop, but i don't know how to fix it.

From my knowledge it may have two possible solutions,

either

we need to relocate the FFMPEG library assets to the SDCard and we have to refer them from our coding, if this is the answer what are all the steps to be followed?

or

Is there any update in the FFMPEG library for android lollipop.

If both are wrong can you provide me with the proper solution.

Many thanks...

Here is my code

```
   try {
            String[] ffmpegCommand = {"/data/data/com.mobvcasting.mjpegffmpeg/ffmpeg", "-r", ""+p.getPreviewFrameRate(), "-b", "1000000", "-vcodec", "mjpeg", "-i", 
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/req_images/frame_%05d.jpg", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/req_images/video.mov"};

            ffmpegProcess = new ProcessBuilder(ffmpegCommand).redirectErrorStream(true).start();            

            OutputStream ffmpegOutStream = ffmpegProcess.getOutputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ffmpegProcess.getInputStream()));

            String line;

            Log.v(LOGTAG,"***Starting FFMPEG***");
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                Log.v(LOGTAG,"***"+line+"***");
            }
            Log.v(LOGTAG,"***Ending FFMPEG***");


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (ffmpegProcess != null) {
            ffmpegProcess.destroy();        
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need an ffmpeg "update". PIE is a compile time setting. You can just compile it yourself with PIE options set.

`CFLAGS="-fPIE -pie"`

see more here:
https://github.com/danielkop/android-ffmpeg/commit/616a099151fb6be05b559adc4c9ed95afacd92c2

Comment: Thanks szatmary. Do you mean, i have to compile FFMPEG using NDK?